# Windows Network driver above TCP

Tags: windows, driver

I would like to write a network driver for WINDOWS, above TCP.
In this driver I would like to modify or to check "on the fly" the incoming HTTP traffic.
How can I implement a such module ? 
Which development environment ?  Which SDK ? 
Do you know about an open source project which do that ?
Do you think libpcap can do that ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry, regarding libpcap : WinPcap receives and sends the packets independently from the host protocols, like TCP-IP. This means that it isn't able to block, filter or manipulate the traffic generated by other programs on the same machine: it simply "sniffs" the packets that transit on the wire. Therefore, it does not provide the appropriate support for applications like traffic shapers, QoS schedulers and personal firewalls.

Comment: Check Windows Filtering platform which could be used for this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366510(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I found ... see "Windows Filtering Platform" documentation.